# How to draw Image pattern with javaFX Canvas

Tags: java, image, javafx, canvas

I want to draw a repeating image on a javafx canvas, is there any way to do it other than manually reapeatedly drawing the same image over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by setting the Paint for filling some area. A subclass of Paint is

https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html

which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks alot! You were right, exactly what I wanted.